# JSF Templating: f:event works, f:viewParam doesn't

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewparams

Following the example of [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html), I have a template and a template client.

**default.xhtml (template):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
  <title>...</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <h:outputStylesheet name="css/screen.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <f:view>
    <ui:insert name="metadata" />
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <img src="resources/gfx/logo.png" />
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content" />
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>
          This is a project.<br />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**edit.xhtml (template client):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  template="/WEB-INF/templates/default.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="metadata">
    <f:metadata>
      <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{myBean.id}" />
      <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.init}"/>
    </f:metadata>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="content">
    ...
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**list.xhtml (the caller of the edit view) contains:**

```
<h:commandLink action="edit" value="#{msgs.edit}">
  <f:param name="id" value="#{myentity.id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

The f:event gets called, but the id (viewParam) is not assigned to the bean. The id is however present in the request parameter map and can be retrieved like this:

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> parameters = ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
if (parameters.containsKey("id")) {
  this.id = Long.valueOf(parameters.get("id"));
}
```

But that's what `<f:viewParam ...>` should take care of (as far as I understood).

What might be wrong?

Comment: How do you call your edit site? If you call it like this `../edit?id=123` it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong.

```
<h:commandLink action="edit" value="#{msgs.edit}">
  <f:param name="id" value="#{myentity.id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

This sends a POST request, not a GET request.

You need to use `<h:link>` instead.

```
<h:link outcome="edit" value="#{msgs.edit}">
  <f:param name="id" value="#{myentity.id}" />
</h:link>
```

#### See also:

- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/4317723#4317723)

Comment: I wasn't really aware that viewParam is not applicable for POST requests.

Comment: No problem. Note that in general, navigating by POST is not user nor SEO friendly. That fact is unrelated to JSF.

Comment: Yeah I usually prefer SEO-friendly GETs, but JSF left a "I prefer POST" impression on me (if that makes any sense). :) Thanks anyways

Comment: This is perhaps heritage of JSF 1.x. There were no standard components available to generate plain GET links/buttons and ignorant developers didn't knew that you can just use plain HTML like `<a>` and `<button>` in a JSF page, or they were overly puristic and didn't want to use plain HTML in a JSF page.